# How to remove unused blocks of code from a source code file?

Tags: c, delphi, ide, conditional-compilation, code-editor

Let’s suppose I have a bunch of source code files (*C* or *Delphi*, i.e., *.c or *.pas). I want to purge them of blocks of text **which are not used in the compilation**. Those blocks are:

1. Comments. They can be removed with regexp. (But, for example, Delphi
   uses the preprocessor directives which look like comments (*“{ is it
   a comment or a directive? }”*), so the regexp would not be trivial.)
2. But the most tricking part is the blocks of code which are excluded
   from the compilation with *#ifdef*. These blocks have to be removed
   too.

So, the question is: *“Is there a way to do it with some program or script?”* Let’s suppose there is a program that can be given a source code file and a list of defined symbols to distinguish unused blocks of code, and it would spit out the cleansed file I want to get.